# How can i display the result in realtime of powershell command or script that is being executed through C# web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, powershell, web-applications

i followed this blogpost https://www.itdroplets.com/create-a-powershell-web-application/ and i have tried the Powershell Web Application it works very well,

however, when i tried to modify in the .aspx.cs file

```
shell.Commands.AddCommand("Get-ChildItem");
```

to

```
shell.Commands.AddCommand("Ping");
```

and

```
shell.Commands.AddParameter("Path", Input.Text);
```

to

```
shell.Commands.AddArgumentr(Input.Text);
```

so that my application can ping the host i specify in the Input TextBox, i did ping succesfully the host that i specify in input textbox but what i noticed is that it wont display the result until the ping command has finished executing...

so my question is there a way to display the output of the ping command in realtime on the result textbox? and is it possible to display the result in some sort of div instead of textbox so the end user can't modify or remove it

i have done some research and i found a similar question https://forums.asp.net/t/2131798.aspx?How+to+execute+a+PowerShell+script+and+continuously+write+the+output+to+a+TextBox+ i have tried his signalR solution exacly as he discribed it but i just can't get it to work...

ps: i am a complete beginner in C# so any help would be appreciated

thank you in Advance,

Comment: Don't use `ping` as that's referring to the system executable `ping.exe`.  Consider using `Test-Connection` or `Test-NetConnection` if you're on Windows 10 / Server 2016+

Comment: thanks for your reply, i don't think that the command or the script are problem, as matter of fact i tested it with ping.exe Test-Connection and Test-NetConnection i still get the same thing,  it wont display the result untill the command finishes executing

Comment: I believe there's some way to get the raw xml output of powershell and stream it to your user, but that's beyond my knowledge as I've never had to do it.

Comment: no problem thanks mate